# How to disable Windows Defender on the domain controller?

Tags: windows, active-directory

I want to disable Windows Defender temporarily on my Windows Server 2016 domain controller to test some things.

The problem is, that while I'm logged in (interactively) as a domain administrator ("Domain Admins"), Windows seems to ignore my actions.

More specifically, when I disable "Real-time protection", nothing happens: after I close the settings and reopen them, the protection is still enabled.

Is it only possible to disable Windows Defender through GPOs, or why can't I disable it using the normal settings?

[image]

Comment: Maybe it is forcefully _enabled_ via GPO so you can't disable it locally.

Comment: If you close the windows defender service via services.msc ?

Comment: @Lenniey In that case I would expect to see "Some settings are managed by your organization".

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, but as far as I know not if set via registry keys. Then it _should_ stay disabled for a while, though. (Can't check it for Server 2016 atm)